# Softlayer Object Storage Python API Time To Live

Tags: python, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

How do I set time to live for a file on object storage?

Looking at the code in https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-object-storage-python/blob/master/object_storage/storage_object.py it takes in (self, data, check_md5) with no TTL option.

```
sl_storage = object_storage.get_client(
    username = environment['slos_username'],
    password = environment['api_key'],
    auth_url = environment['auth_url']
)

# get container 
sl_container = sl_storage.get_container(environment['object_container'])
# create "pointer" to cointainer file fabfile.zip

sl_file = sl_container[filename]
myzip = open(foldername + filename, 'rb')
sl_file.create()

sl_file.send(myzip, TIME_TO_LIVE_PARAM=100)
```

I also tried according to https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-object-storage-python/blob/master/object_storage/container.py

```
sl_file['ttl'] = timetolive
```

But it doesn't work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the "ttl" is available in the headers, The "TTL" header is available when your container has enabled CDN.

so to verify that the ttl header exist you can use this code line:

```
sl_storage['myContainserName']['MyFileName'].headers
```

then you can update the tll using this line code:

```
sl_storage['myContainserName']['MyFileName'].update({'x-cdn-ttl':'3600'})
```

in case the ttl values does not exist and you have the cdn enabled try to create the header using this line code:

```
  sl_storage['myContainserName']['MyFileName'].create({'x-cdn-ttl':'3600'})
```

Regards

Comment: ah I see.  How do I specify the "expires at" if I want the file removed from object storage and not just have the cache expire?

Comment: I think that functionality does not exist, I cannot see anything about that in OpenStack http://developer.openstack.org/api-ref-objectstorage-v1.html , softlayer object storage is based in open stack if you know how to do it in open stack it should work as well in softlayer

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up the header "X-Delete-At: 1417341600" where 1417341600 is a Unix timestamp see more information here http://docs.openstack.org/developer/swift/overview_expiring_objects.html

using the Python client you can use the update method:
https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-object-storage-python/blob/master/object_storage/storage_object.py#L210-L216

```
sl_storage['myContainserName']['MyFileName'].update({'X-Delete-At':1417341600})
```

Regards